# How rest password HyperFile

Tags: windev

I have data files WinDev HFSQL and I would like to create a report with Crystal reports, but I do not know the password of hyperfile files.
any solution please ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IF it is not on a production machine, AND the analysis is not password protected?

Then you can backup the data (not .zip and with .ndx), uninstall the HFSQL server, delete the \ProgramData\PCSOFT directory reinstall HFSQL (preferable newest), restore data (only data), then you should have a database without a password.

WinDev own HFSQL files are password protected, so we'r programmers (18+ WinDev) do not know the password... (but we do not need it anyway)

Data in SCM, there is a known password, seek in wxforum.info, new forum on facebook for WinDev US, maybe you can get the password there